# How to use dependency injection in a method or property?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Normally I use Dependency injection in the constructor of a class.
The dependencies are registered in the unity container, f.e.:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, MyClass>();
```

But in one class it is not possible to inject with the constructor (it's a third party class which I inherit from and the default constructor (without injection) MUST be used.

How can I use my MyClass in this class too?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/Method-injection-using-unity-container

Comment: That's far too broad a question. Some DI containers support method injection, some don't. Are you asking for a *specific* container and framework?

Comment: For example, ASP.NET *Core* provides [action injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.0#action-injection-with-fromservices) irrespective of the DI container. ASP.NET MVC though doesn't, unless someone writes an action filter that resolves dependencies using a specific DI container. ASP.NET Core includes those filters and uses the DI abstractions to call whichever DI container is configured

Comment: you can use: IUnityContainer.Resolve

Comment: You can't add another constructor that calls the base parameterless constructor? I think it'd be helpful if you told us specifically what class from what library you're trying to extend.

Answer (score 0):

If the main constraint is calling the default constructor of the 3rd party class, can't you do something like this?

```
public class InheritedClass : ThirdPartyClass
{
   private IMyInterface _myInterface;

   // the default ctr of the 3rd party class is still being called
   public InheritedClass(IMyInterface myInterface, string arg) : base(arg)
   {
       _myInterface = myInterface;
   }
}
```

In case you actually mean your own inherited class has a certain constructor that you have to use, then why not do something like this ?

```
 public class InheritedClass : ThirdPartyClass
{
   // Constructor that has to be used
    public InheritedClass(string arg) : base(arg)
    {
    }

    // Ctr with DI that also calls the required default ctr - could be used instead..
    public InheritedClass(IMyInterface myInterface, string arg) : this(arg)
    {
        _myInterface = myInterface;
    }
}
```

In case none of these apply to your case, what you're looking for is the concept of Method Injection, an example could be [this one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-dependency-injection-functionmethod-injection/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't understand how this is hard.

> (it's a third party class which I inherit from and the default constructor (without injection)

Assume this is a 3rd Party Class that you inherit from:

```
public abstract MyClassBase
{
  public MyClassBase()
  {
  }

  public abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

What prevents you from deriving and injecting?

```
public MyClassDerived
{
  private IInjectioned _injection;

  public MyClassDerived(IInjectioned injection)
    // Call default constructor without params
    : base()
  {
    _injection = injection;
  }

  public override void DoSomething()
  {
    _injection.DoSomething();
  }      
}
```